# Swap nested ternary expressions to cond using ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have working code using nested ternary expressions. Is there any way to make it cleaner using ramda.js or another functional helper? Will [cond](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) be a good choice?

I'm new to ramda and I don't know exactly how to convert that piece of code to ramda way.

```
  const enhance: React$HOC<*, InitialProps> = compose(
      withProps(props => ({
        iconColor: props.isPriority ? (props.isCompleted ? variables.color.lightpurple : variables.color.purple ) : variables.color.gray3,
        iconName: props.isPriority ? 'star-full' : 'star-empty',
      }))
    )
```

converting just that insane long line:

```
iconColor: props.isPriority ? (props.isCompleted ? variables.color.lightpurple : variables.color.purple ) : variables.color.gray3,
```

would be more than enougth.

Answer (score 0):

`R.cond` is definitely one option for removing the nesting. This could also be combined with [`R.applySpec`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec) to produce an object whose values are all derived from the same argument (`props` in your instance).

```
const enhance: React$HOC<*, InitialProps> = compose(withProps(R.applySpec({
    iconColor: R.cond([
        [({ isPriority }) => !isPriority, () => variables.color.gray3],
        [({ isCompleted }) => isCompleted, () => variables.color.lightpurple],
        [() => true, () => variables.color.purple]
    ]),
    iconName: ({ isPriority }) => isPriority ? 'star-full' : 'star-empty'
})))
```